# Magento Multistore categories giving error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, multistore, fatal-error

This is my second store with second root category on my single magento installation.

- WEBSITE: main website (Code: base)
  MAIN WEBSITE STORE: (Root Category: Default Category)
  DEFAULT STORE VIEW: (Code: default)
- WEBSITE: Business Website (Code: business)
  MAIN WEBSITE STORE: (Root Category: Business Store)
  DEFAULT STORE VIEW: (Code: business_store_view)

Everything is fine except when I click on the category in mega menu, it gives the following error:

> Warning: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: require_once(app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php on line 9' in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(9): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'require_once(ap...', '/home/content/8...', 9, Array)
>   #1 app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(9): require_once()
>   #2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(323): include('/home/content/8...')
>   #3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(293): Mage_C in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
>
> Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php' (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:app/code/core:lib:.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php on line 9

Comment: Since this error comes directly from a 3rd party module (Smartwave) we're unable to reproduct the error. But it seems you are missing a file. Check if it exists