# Multistore feature troubleshooting

Tags: category, cart, multistore, b2b, multidomain

I'm asking you your help because I created two stores in the same Magento installation :

1. store.example.com : for customers (default store)
2. b2b.example.com : for retailers

The installation was done and I can access to the both stores.

Unfortunately, the category navigation is not working for the "b2b" store, I got this error :

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php' (include_path='/home/example/store/app/code/local:/home/example/store/app/code/community:/home/example/store/app/code/core:/home/example/store/lib:.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib/php') in /home/example/store/app/code/local/Etheme/Ajaxshop/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php on line 9``

1. http://store.example.com/shoes.html is OK
2. http://b2b.example.com/shoes.html is wrong

The others links are working: http://b2b.example.com/checkout/cart/ or http://b2b.example.com/checkout/onepage/

Moreover, the cart is common of the two stores when I switched between the both stores. Is it a normal work please?

Comment: this seems related to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68244/magento-multistore-categories-giving-error

Comment: when you disable Etheme_Ajaxshop module, is there any other error?

Comment: Please update your question if needed, but do NOT post questions as answers.  Also I recommend to contact the extension vendor directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response.I have the same issue on my multiple sites on a single domain and solved by this way.So in future, if someone faces such issue try code like my one.

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true );
if($url == 'http://base site url/'){
require_once('app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php');
}else{
    require_once('../app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php');
}
```

The `if statement` will add controller file for base site, and `else statement` will add file for sub domains.Hope this will help someone.Thanks